# How to find proxy server and password from .pac file

Tags: proxy, pac

I am using dynatrace ajax edition and it requires an proxy server and password to connect to dynatrace server.

The problem is I ONLY have the .pac file URL that we use at work.

Is it possible to know which proxy server and port my requests resolve to so that I can provide the proxy server name and password directly?

I have checked few links in the stackoverflow community but they do not seem to answer this question.

Like: [How to discover de proxy used in a pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068728/how-to-discover-de-proxy-used-in-a-pac)

I am using an windows 7 64 bit system with IE8.

Thanks,
Ayusman

Comment: For me, after downloading the .pac file specified in the connection proxy settings, finding the proxy URL inside was rather easy, since there only was one URL looking like that. (Apart from additional local proxies.. which I did not need.)

Comment: @AndreasReiff for me it was much difficult to find out manually. In the past in my enterprise pac file; it was easy; but the current organization I am in the pac file is really big with many conditional paths; so it was not easy finding out using manual inspection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to discover de proxy used in a pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068728/how-to-discover-de-proxy-used-in-a-pac)

Comment: You can just read the `.pac` file, it is plain text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After trolling through some more google search results,

[This nifty tool](https://github.com/manugarg/pacparser) helped me perfectly

Please note that I was on a 64 bit windows 7 machine, still it worked fine.

Comment: Forwarding is in fact broken :D

Answer (score 1):

Hit the URL in the address bar of the browser. It should download the file. Open the file with any text editor. Looking at the content of the file, you can easily find out the proxy IP/port being used. This worked for me. Hope it helps others too.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hit' the URL in the address bar?

Comment: @tonneofash The user wrote in the question- "The problem is I ONLY have the .pac file URL that we use at work." In the proxy setting of windows, many organisations store the location of a proxy script file, whose extension ends with .pac. If you can't find anything related to .pac in your proxy settings on windows system, then this question is quite unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

answer from 2023:

use this online tool: https://thorsen.pm/proxyforurl

it works online, copy and paste your PAC there, set the URL you want to visit, and let it run the javascript

Answer (score -5):

To find your Web Proxy, simply go to:

http://www.whatismyproxy.com/

This web page will display information about your proxy server.

Comment: This just gives the public IP address. Often the proxy server has a different, private IP address, somewhere behind the public one.